# Passing a Jenkins variable to behave command line argument

Tags: python, jenkins, command-line, python-behave

I'm trying to use jenkins to run a python behave regression test pack.

I have a script block that sets the variable, I then use a shell command to prove that the variable is successful set.

However, when I run my python behave command the variable is not being passed successfully.

```
stage('End to end tests') {
        steps {

            script{
                if(params.containsKey("envname")){
                  env_e2e = "https://url" + params.envname + ".com"
                }else{
                  env_e2e = "https://url.com"
                }

            withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'ui_test_user',
                                    usernameVariable: 'UI_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'UI_PASSWORD']]) {
                                        sh 'sudo --preserve-env scl enable rh-python36 "cp krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf"'
                                        sh 'sudo --preserve-env scl enable rh-python36  "echo ${UI_PASSWORD} | kinit ${UI_USERNAME}@****.com"'
            }

            sh """
                echo "my env ${env_e2e}"
                """
            sh 'sudo --preserve-env scl enable rh-python36 "python -m pip install --force-reinstall dist/*.whl"'
            sh 'sudo --preserve-env scl enable rh-python36 "behave -D ENV_E2E=${env_e2e} --tags=-skip --junit"'
            }
        }
         post {
            always {
                archive "reports/*"
                junit 'reports/*.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

ENV_E2E always resolves to blank

In my python behave frame work I have this environment.py file

```
def before_all(context):
env_var = context.config.userdata['ENV_E2E']
logging.info(env_var)
print(len(env_var))
context.pythonlib = PythonLib(service_endpoint_url=env_var)
```

This just returns an error at run time that env_vars len = 0 and the service_endpoint is badly format as it expects http/https

Thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to use triple double quoted strings, """

```
sh """
sudo --preserve-env scl enable rh-python36 "behave -D ENV_E2E=${env_e2e} --tags=-skip --junit"
"""
```